# How do I add ABS Library to Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm new to android studio and I am having trouble installing the ActionBarSherlock library in android studio.  I've tried adding it as a module but my computer just freezes when I try to add it.  I'm getting very frustrated and I would appreciate any help resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use the ActionBarSherlock library in Android Studio is to use a gradle dependency instead of using a local module.

Just add this library to your dependencies block inside your `proj/myApp/build.gradle` and sync your porject.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to increase your memory via vmx settings. It is usually set to 512 by default. Increase it to 1024 and that should do the trick.